# Programmatically set the selected value of a dijit Select widget

Tags: dojo

I'm populating a dijit select widget with options whenever another select widget's value changes.

In my app, theres a dropdown menu for "Bus Route" and a dropdown menu for "Bus Stop".
Users have assigned bus routes and stops that should be updateable.

So when the page first loads, the route dropdown box has all routes available, and the route you are currently assigned to is the selected value. The stop menu is loaded with all stops associated with that route, but there is no selected value, so, as by default, it's the first option.

Whenever the user changes the currently selected route, the stop menu changes accordingly and is populated with all stops associated with that route.

My question is, with dojo, how can I set the "Selected" option in the stop menu?

I want it to be clear which stop is currently assigned to that user, instead of the "selected" stop being the first option in the route.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

```
selectWidget.set("value", someValue);
```

If you are specifying options via the `options` property (array of objects with `label`, `value`, etc.), then `someValue` should match the `value` of one of those objects.  (Note that you can also specify `selected: true` right within one of the objects in the array passed to `options`.)

If you are providing items from a dojo.data store via the `store` property, then `someValue` should match the identity of one of the store's items.

(edit) NOTE: I assumed above that by "dijit select widget" you are referring to `dijit.form.Select`.  If you are actually using `dijit.form.ComboBox` or `dijit.form.FilteringSelect`, the same line of code still holds true, as applicable to stores in the last paragraph.  In the case of declarative instantiation with a `select` tag, ComboBox and FilteringSelect still create a store, whose items' identities are the values of the options within the select tag.

Answer (score 4):

```
//With dojo version 1.9
//search for the item in store dojo/store/Memory with the corresponding id value
var objItem = store.get("1");
//set the combobox's item
comboBox.set("item", objItem);
```

Comment: This was exactly where I was looking for!