# dojo and dynamically added options to dijit.form.select

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I use dojo 1.8.2 and here is my problem (I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869805/programmatically-set-the-selected-value-of-a-dijit-select-widget) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159140/dijit-form-select-wont-set-value-programmatically) question, but they eren't helpful) :

My `JS` code receives from server some data in `JSON` format. With that, I dynamically create some options for `dijit.form.select`:

```
var select = registry.byId('zgloszenieDoFirmyEdycja');
for (var uzytkownik in dane.uzytkownicy){
    var idUzytkownika = dane.uzytkownicy[uzytkownik]['_id']['$oid'];
    var imie = dane.uzytkownicy[uzytkownik].imie;
    var nazwisko = dane.uzytkownicy[uzytkownik].nazwisko;
    var wybrany = (idUzytkownika == id);
    var opcja = {};

    opcja.label = imie + ' ' + nazwisko;
    opcja.value = idUzytkownika;
    opcja.selected = wybrany;

    console.log(wybrany);
    console.log(idUzytkownika + ' | ' + imie + ' ' + nazwisko);
    console.log(opcja);

    select.addOption(opcja);
    /*select.addOption({
        label: imie + ' ' + nazwisko,
        value: idUzytkownika,
        selected: wybrany
    });*/
}
```

This is my console output:

```
false
5077d2a1e4b0f5734a9850a1 | zero zero
Object { label="zero zero", value="5077d2a1e4b0f5734a9850a1", selected=false}
true
50c0776f096aa0e726d221a3 | raz raz
Object { label="raz raz", value="50c0776f096aa0e726d221a3", selected=true}
false
50d019c3096aa862c6898cdb | dwa dwa
Object { label="dwa dwa", value="50d019c3096aa862c6898cdb", selected=false}
```

But after the `dijit.form.select` is updated, the `selected` parameter gets somehow mixed up and is set to true not for the option that I set it for, but for the first one:

```
console.log(select);
...
Object[Object { label="zero zero", value="5077d2a1e4b0f5734a9850a1", selected=true},      
       Object { label="raz raz", value="50c0776f096aa0e726d221a3", selected=false}, 
       Object { label="dwa dwa", value="50d019c3096aa862c6898cdb", selected=false}
]
...
```

I don't understand why it happens, any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking into the source code of `dijit/form/_FormSelectWidget` the issue is caused by the fact, that if no option is selected then the first option gets selected by default. By the time you add the first option this condition is met and the first option gets selected.

**Workaround**: add all options at once as an array:

```
var select = registry.byId("select1");

option1 = { value: "o1", label: "option 1", selected: false };
option2 = { value: "o2", label: "option 2", selected: true };

select.addOption([option1, option2]); // add all options at once as an array
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/BfTXC/